# Floating Point Precision using REST

Tags: sql-server, rest, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm pulling timeseries data in from a MS-SQL database using REST.  I've found that the floating point precision goes down from a value like 0.00166667 to 0.002 when I'm using REST to retrieve data, but using the DB designer's own tools, the precision is maintained.

Is this a limitation of the REST method, or is it something specific to the implementation?

Just to clarify -- my work is using a proprietary database that uses MS-SQL as its backbone.  It's not open-source so I can't poke around and see how requests are being handled.

A SOAP method is offered, which I'm going to try to implement to compare, but I'm more concerned whether or not this is a REST problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representational State Transfer is just a general style of client-server architecture. It doesn't specify anything nearly so detailed such the appropriate handling of floating point values. The only constraints it imposes are things like the communication should be "stateless". So the concepts of REST exist on a higher level of abstraction and the issue you are seeing must be something specific to the implementation of the service that is providing the floating point values.

Comment: I've been using REST methods to access data for a few months now, and I guess I didn't fully understand the depth of the abstraction taking place.